# Nginx : How to translate example.org to www.example.org

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-server

When I open `example.org`, I'd like my browser to translate it to `www.example.org`, how should I change my configuration to do so ?

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.org www.example.org;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just redirect:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.org;

    return 301 http://www.example.org;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.org;
    ...
}
```